# Object flipped inside-out?

Tags: export, edit-mode, error

I'm currently working on a cosplay and this is my first blender project. I managed to make the crown by watching a load of tutorials and have tried to solve this issue by myself for a few hours now.

My faces are all flipped to blue on the outside. I've added seams etc. The model is scaled to a scale of my own head that's 1:1 ratio. When I try to export paper model it gives me the invalid input error: object is flipped inside-out.

Can anybody tell me what might be wrong?

[image: error code]

[image: model]

Comment: In normals, blue means outside and red means inside, red is supposed to be inside of the object(for example in 3d printing it would tell that blue side is surface and red side is supposed to be filled with inside filament).. If your mesh in enclosed and it is not 1 sided plane, you can just press Alt+N and select Recalculate outside... This will make whole mesh blue and if there are some that is left red, you can simply select them, by faces, press Alt+N again and choose Flip

Comment: The error message is referring to the scale though... can it be that you have a negative scale on the object, like -1 in one or more directions instead of 1? Applying the scale is suggested by the error message, did you try that?

Comment: Agree with Gordon - Error message is telling you the problem is related to _Non-Uniform Scale_ - Select the object in object mode, then press Ctrl+A (Apply), and select "Scale". Then try to export again.